# Subreport Data band - KeepTogether Not Working

Tags: fastreport

I have a Child band on the Main report, which contains a subreport object. I'm trying to keep the Data band in this subreport together, but it breaks even though I flagged the band as KeepTogether=true.

I'm wondering if this is an issue with a subreport, or what? Any ideas most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you use FR VCL or FR FMX - place TfrxSubreport on the stretched TfrxChild band, set TfrxChild.AllowSplit to False, TfrxSubreport.PRintOnParent to True